# Str::title no longer working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the code below that worked in Laravel 4.2 but no longer in Laravel 5.  `Str::title()` is no longer working.  If I echo out `$development` after the title runs, it is all in uppercase.  However, if I do `echo \Illuminate\Support\Str::title($development);` it comes out in title case (e.g. GOLDEN GATE becomes Golden Gate).

Here is the code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class SubdivisionUpdate {
    public static function update($tempListing)
    {
        $city         = $tempListing->City;
        $subcondoname = $tempListing->SubCondoName;
        $development  = $tempListing->Development;

        // Clean Up Inputs
        $subcondoname = Str::title(trim($subcondoname));
        $development = Str::title(trim($development));
```

Comment: It works, anyways, try `title_case($development)` to be sure.

Comment: Is there a place that tells us what they all became?  I can't find any documentation.  For example, Str::title() becomes title_case, Str::slug became str_slug() or what not.

Answer (score 1):

The string helpers use a global function syntax in Laravel 5.x. You're looking for `title_case($some_string)`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#strings